# Finding an item in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm looking to obtain the value of `student_id` from the following value, but I'm not sure how, because the value is within a nested `dict`. How can I get to `student_id`?

```
{
    "specification": {
        "[student_id]": {
            "grade_level": "numeric grade level between 1 and 6",
            "score": "Test score, numeric, between 1 and 4",
            "school_id": "school id"
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "grade_level": 1,
            "score": 3,
            "school_id": "PS0001"
        },
        "2": {
            "grade_level": 1,
            "score": 4,
            "school_id": "PS0001"
        }
    }
}
```

So far I've tried

```
['specification'].keys()
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried?

Comment: Something like: `dict.specification.stduent_id`, it depends on what language you are using.

Comment: And what does ['specification'].keys() return?